# sharedPreference will not save data while being invoked in onItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I get a Set from a sharedPreference, I add a value to it, it saves fine. But when I completely close down the app and reopen... that value is gone. THis problem does not happen while I am doing it in an activity, but only in my Spinner listener code.

Here is what I have tried: I passed in the preference and editor object from the activity to the listener class through it's constructor. Therefore, no need to initilize anything. I still get the same error.

Also, I tried to start a instance of the Activity and save do my saving there... but that didnt work either.

I was not able to provide you any code, because it is on a different computer... but the code is not the problem, because that same code works great in an activity

update: code added

```
public class SpinnerListener1 extends Activity
        implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    SpinnerAdpter  spinnerAdapter1;
    Spinner addCtAvail;
    String type;
    Context c;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

  //  String value;


    public SpinnerListener1(SpinnerAdpter  vSpinnerAdpter, Spinner  vaddCtAvail, String type,  Context ctx,SharedPreferences prefs ,SharedPreferences.Editor edit ){
        this.spinnerAdapter1 = vSpinnerAdpter;
        this.addCtAvail = vaddCtAvail;
        this.type = type;
        this.c = ctx;
        this.prefs = prefs;
        this.edit = edit;


    }//SpinnerListener1

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        String selection = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

        if (selection.equals("new")) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder11 = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
            builder11.setTitle("Add a new value to List");
            builder11.setMessage("Please Enter a Value");

            builder11.setCancelable(true);
            builder11.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            final EditText input = new EditText(c);
            input.setId(0);
            builder11.setView(input);


            builder11.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Tabs1 tabInstance = new Tabs1();
                    String newCTvalue = input.getText().toString();

                    // have the new entry appear in spinner:
                    spinnerAdapter1.remove("new");
                    spinnerAdapter1.add(newCTvalue);
                    spinnerAdapter1.add("new");
                    addCtAvail.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter1);
                    addCtAvail.setSelection(spinnerAdapter1.getCount());
                    saveNewValue(newCTvalue, type);

                }
            })
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,     int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            builder11.create().show();
        }

    }//onItemSelected

    public void saveNewValue(String value, String prefname){

        Set set = prefs.getStringSet(prefname,null);
        set.add(value);
        edit.putStringSet(prefname , set);
        edit.commit();








    }//saveNewValue



    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }


}//SpinnerListener
```

here is the code for my TabActivity which launches this listner:

```
public void createSpinner(View view, String type, String texttoShow , Spinner addLoadType){

        //prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Tabs1.this);

        prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SpinnerPrefs", 0);
        edit = prefs.edit();
        getSpinnerSharedPref(type);
        final SpinnerAdpter  spinnerAdapterLoadType = new SpinnerAdpter(this);
        spinnerAdapterLoadType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        SpinnerListener1 spinnerlistenerLoadType = new SpinnerListener1(spinnerAdapterLoadType, addLoadType,type, Tabs1.this, prefs, editor);
        addLoadType.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerlistenerLoadType);

        getSpinnerPrefandPopulate(type,spinnerAdapterLoadType );
        spinnerAdapterLoadType.add(texttoShow);
        addLoadType.setAdapter(spinnerAdapterLoadType);
        addLoadType.setSelection(spinnerAdapterLoadType.getCount()); //display hint
```

Comment: add your code snippet, that would help

Comment: I would disagree. the code is definitely the problem. nothing any of us can do without the code. When you get a chance go to the other computer and post the code here

Comment: what context do you use to get sharedPreference

Comment: ok hold on, let me grab it

Comment: ok i added the code for my listener class